# Application in Right Culture but only returning key name not value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Returning En-gb for the default culture but still not finding resource file please help im pulling out my skin here.

I am using .net core 3.1 with the layout of the file system as such I have made the edits according to my previous so question so this is why I am opening a new question

[image]

However, I am only getting the key name being returned not the value of the resource no matter what I do.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddLocalization(opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-GB"), new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), };

            opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");

            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
            // Maintain property names during serialization. See:
            // https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
        services.Configure<ConnectionStringConfig>(Configuration);
        //lets inject the connection string to the data layer 
        //but we should be using the api layer for any heavy lifting.
        services.AddHttpClient("externalservice", c =>
        {
            // Assume this is an "external" service which requires an API KEY
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
        });

        // Add Kendo UI services to the services container
        services.AddKendo();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        SetUpLocalization(app);
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }



        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


    }
    private static void SetUpLocalization(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
          new CultureInfo("en-GB")
        };

        var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB", "en-GB"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,

        };
        options.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
        {
            // My custom request culture logic
            return new ProviderCultureResult("en");
        }));

        // Find the cookie provider with LINQ
        options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(async context =>
        {
            // My custom request culture logic
            return new ProviderCultureResult("en");
        }));



        // Configure the Localization middleware
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options);



    }
}
```

You, Will, see here that I have indeed set up the app.UseRequestLocalization(options); Before all else by calling its method

[image]

This is a short video of the issue I am having.
https://streamable.com/ercem

Also Please note I still have the correct tag helpers installed.

[image: the]

Comment: Have you set `NeutralResourcesLanguage` at assembly level somewhere?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that is not noted in the documentation however it is getting the en-gb.

Comment: You can try to define it `[assembly:NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-GB")]` and check the result

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski But .net core does not have assembly info file ? I am .net core 3.1

Comment: You can set it in class, where `Main` method is defined, as it shown in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute?view=netcore-3.1) You don't need assembly info for that

Comment: I still dont think its the issue for the property resources not found is always true

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things you need to focus on:

- You need to be sure that your resource file is created
  by yourself instead of moving from other folders.
- You need to be sure that your Project Name and `Assembly name`
  and `Default namespace` should be the same.
  [image]

To fix your issue, change your Assembly name to `RoundTableWebSite.Erp`.

Comment: I did what you said but this is still not working I have logged it n as a bug in asp.net core 3.1

Comment: No,it is not a bug in asp.net core 3.1. Maybe your project has any other configuration or you changed something but you do not realized.

Answer (score 0):

For Me, I rebuilt my project I also added[image] the following into the startup cs config.

```
var supportedCultures = new string[] { "en-GB", "fr-FR" };
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
options
.AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
.AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
.SetDefaultCulture("en-gb")
.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
{
return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en-gb"));
}))
);
```

Yes, UseRequestLocalization is in the documentation but the extra steps are not also please make sure that you are doing this at the very start.